# Does Pimcore provide possibility to export Hotspots and Markers additional data in DataHub GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, pimcore, pimcore-datahub

Asset Hotspots have 'add Data' in context menu.
We can add related objects / fileds / documents / etc there.

[image]

**How to export this data in GraphQL? I see only '__typename' property.**

Sample query:

```
{
  getCategoryListing(defaultLanguage: "en") {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        categoryimage {
          image {
            fullpath
          }
           hotspots {
            name
            top
            height
            left
            width            
            data {
              __typename
            }
          }
          marker {
            name
            top
            left
            data {
              __typename
            }
          }
         
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is provided by GraphQL itself.

1. Check that you granted reading rights to object class that you are trying to access otherwise you will see 'object: null'
2. learch which object types you get using __typename
3. When you know the type name and have access to that object, just get its data

Sample:

```
... on property_text {
                type
                name
                text
              }
```

or

```
... on object_product {
                        sku
                      }
```

See the documentation here: https://pimcore.com/docs/data-hub/current/GraphQL/Query/Query_Samples/Sample_Element_Properties.html

Sample query to get additional data from Pimcore Hotspots and Markers on Hotspotimage:

```
{
  getCategoryListing(defaultLanguage: "en") {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        id
        categoryimage {
          image {
            fullpath
          }
          hotspots {
            name
            top
            height
            left
            width
            data {
              __typename
              ... on property_text {
                type
                name
                text
              }
              ... on property_object {
                type
                name
                object {
                  __typename
                  ... on object_product {
                    sku
                  }
                  ... on element {
                    __typename
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          marker {
            name
            top
            left
            data {
              __typename
              ... on property_text {
                type
                name
                text
              }
              ... on property_object {
                type
                name
                object {
                  __typename
                  ... on object_product {
                    sku
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```