# pimcore: make uuid available in datahub - graphql

Tags: pimcore, graphql-pimcore

How to make uuid available in datahub - graphql?

Via the datahub interface i cannot see a proper way to add the linked uuid, is this possible?

The graphql api would be used for a third-party api, uuid's seems the best way to identy entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) I was using SKU instead

```
... on object_product {
                        sku
                      }
```

[Does Pimcore provide possibility to export Hotspots and Markers additional data in DataHub GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271581/does-pimcore-provide-possibility-to-export-hotspots-and-markers-additional-data)
It looks easier to me.

(2) But you have the ability to create a custom GraphQL mutation https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Datahub/GraphQL/Mutation/Add_Custom_Mutations/

(3) Also you can create calculated field having UUID as value
https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Calculated_Value_Type/
https://github.com/orgs/pimcore/discussions/7723